# UIScrolview adding some extra space for subviews

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, slider

I'm trying to create a dynamic image slider using UIScrollView. so before I segue to the intended page , I send how many images are needed, and then set the scrollview to have those images as subviews, and scroll through them automatically usin 5 seconds NSTimer till the end, then goes back to the beginning .

The problem occurs when the Scrollview goes through the images for the first time, it displays the images + part of the next image . Then when Swiping to the next image , it shows part of the 3ed image .. ect

Once the scrollview  goes through all the images for the first time, then go back to the first image , everything is fine, and all images take the right size .

I tried everything that I can think of, but no luck ! maybe I'm using the wrong view for this job ? I don't know ..

This is the function I'm using to configure the uiscrolview (called in ViewDidlayout) :

```
scrollview = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.scrolSV.frame.size.height)];
    scrollview.delegate = self;

    [scrollview setPagingEnabled:YES];
    [scrollview setAlwaysBounceHorizontal:NO];
    [scrollview setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator:NO];
    [scrollview setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];
    scrollview.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    scrollview.clipsToBounds= YES;

    CGFloat xOrigin ;

    NSArray *  tempList = [self.sightseeing.images allObjects];

    NSSortDescriptor *  sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"image_counter"
                                                 ascending:YES];

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self.is_image = %@", @(YES)];
    ImagesList = [tempList filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
    ImagesList = [ImagesList sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];
    self.paging.numberOfPages = [ImagesList count];
    selectedOffset = 0 ;

    for (int i = 0 ; i< [ImagesList count]; i++){

        xOrigin = self.view.frame.size.width * i ;


        Images * object = [ImagesList objectAtIndex:i];
        UIImageView * imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xOrigin, 0, scrollview.frame.size.width, scrollview.frame.size.height)];
        imageView.autoresizingMask = NO ;

        if (object.image.length > 5) {
            imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:object.image];
        }
        else
        {
            imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:Image_Placeholder];
        }


        [imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];
        [scrollview addSubview:imageView];

    }



    [scrollview setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
    [scrollview setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.scrolSV.frame.size.width *  [ImagesList count] , self.scrolSV.frame.size.height)];
    [self.scrolSV addSubview:scrollview];
```

This is ScrolDidScrol method :

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{

    [imageTimer invalidate];
    if (![imageTimer isValid]) {
        imageTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:Timer_Length target:self selector:@selector(updateImages) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    }
    int offset = (int)scrollview.contentOffset.x /scrollView.frame.size.width;
    self.paging.currentPage = offset;
    if (selectedOffset != offset) {
        selectedOffset = offset;
        UIImageView * imageV= [scrollView.subviews objectAtIndex:offset];

        Images * image = [ImagesList objectAtIndex:offset];

        if (![image.image length]) {

            [QBRequest downloadFileFromClassName:Sightseeing_Table_Name objectID:self.sightseeing.object_id fileFieldName:image.field_id
                                    successBlock:^(QBResponse *response, NSData *loadedData) {
                                        if (loadedData.length > 100) {
                                            image.image = loadedData;
                                            imageV.image = [UIImage imageWithData:image.image];
                                            [imageV setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];
                                        }

                                    } statusBlock:^(QBRequest *request, QBRequestStatus *status) {

                                    } errorBlock:^(QBResponse *error) {

                                    }];
        }
    }


}
```

This is the image when first time viewed [image]

After going through images, then it shows like : 
[image]

Comment: Are you using iOS or MacOS? You tagged with iOS but probably refer to the MacOS specific function `viewDidLayout` (which you spelled ViewDidlayout).

Comment: it is iOS, as you can see in the screenshots I shared  .

Comment: True! So where do you set up the scroll view?

Comment: ViewDidLayout, but I also tried to set it up on ViewDidLoad, WillApear, And DidApear

I got the same result every time .

Answer (score 0):

I implemented something similar a number of years ago in the Ventura County Animal Services (VCAS) mobile app (still available for free download).  I used a library called FGallery by Grant Davis.  I don't know if this is still available, but they did a nice job including support for both thumbnail and full-sized image viewing, loading indicators, the ability to display a placeholder image if the actual image hasn't finished downloading etc.  I would take a look for yourself if you can.  Maybe you just need to borrow some of their techniques, or, just use what they've done.  It was extremely quick, and my employer was very demanding in that regard.

https://github.com/gdavis/FGallery-iPhone

Comment: The code seems really old ! but lemme give it a try! Thanks Michael

Comment: It IS really old! :-D But, it works really well!  Try the VCAS app to see it in action.